# Anime guess Riddle

Tags: wordplay, knowledge

I'm searching for the name of an anime. Knowledge from the anime is required so maybe, if you havent seen it, you cant figure it out. I hope you have fun :)

> Arrrgh and a roman goddess are trying magic
>   together with splash girl and the 28-year-old grandpa,
>   the lightning and fire freaks and glutton sheep
>   as well as the only bird I know who can gaze that special

Bonus: Name the other characters I didn't mention :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this maybe

> Black Clover?
>  Arrrgh is Asta,
>  roman goddess is Juno :D

Comment: finally I thought it was too hard :) what made you find out?

Comment: Well, it wasn't easy.. it helped when I checked the roman goddesses, when I saw Juno it kinda clicked, then also the Arrrgh made sense .. Great job! :D