# Anime guess Riddle #2

Tags: wordplay, knowledge

[Like in my first part,](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75173/anime-guess-riddle) I'm searching for the name of an anime. Knowledge from the anime is required so maybe, if you havent seen it, you cant figure it out. I hope you have fun :)

> My MC is the worlds best terrorist, his friends are his sidekicks and his worst nightmare.
>   His hobbies are ripping off royals and controlling people
>   But in the end he's a real good guy

Hint

> Season 1 ended with one of the biggest cliffhangers I've ever seen, but Season 2 made Season 1 useless

Comment: Argh I think I got the answer but have to watch the ending of s1 to be able to explain the hint. Definetly doing it this evening.

Comment: @Doomenik I'm waiting ... I got nothing else todo :D. But you can write your guess in [rot13](https://www.rot13.com/) so i can say if it's right

Comment: rot13(Pbqr Trnff)

Comment: @Doomenik thats right, but you need to watch even the whole season 2 to explain the last sentence :D

Comment: I watched it at least 3 times and I remember the ending very well. I´m just not completly sure about the cliffhanger. Watched so many animes that the storylines are a little bit mixed in my mind :D

Comment: @Doomenik oh ... well have fun :L . Youre a real otaku ... (adore)

Comment: I don't think this is a puzzle. It's a trivia question, sure, but trivia isn't necessarily a puzzle. There's no insight required to solve this -- just knowledge of anime.

Comment: @Deusovi is it ok, if I remove the riddle tag?

Comment: Removing the riddle tag would be *accurate*. But it wouldn't change the fact that this is not a puzzle. It's not a problem with your tagging, but with the question itself.

Comment: @Deusovi I tagged trivia and I especially informed that anime knowlegde is needed. I think it's a nice riddle, what's reflected in the votes. Call it a riddle for otakus

Comment: Those are accurate tags; this question does indeed involve trivia and anime knowledge. But you need *more* than trivia to make a puzzle! "Identify this thing" is *not* a puzzle. The problem is not the tagging, but that the question itself is **not a puzzle**. It is a trivia question. Trivia questions can be *part* of a puzzle, but there needs to be some manner of misdirection -- some trick that gives people an "aha" moment. This does not have that.

Comment: @Deusovi what do you suggest to do? making the questions harder, stopping, or changing the way I made this question/riddle (not sure anymore how to call it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85793/discussion-between-deusovi-and-jannis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely

> Code Geass

---

"My MC is the worlds best terrorist"

> The main character is Lelouch Lamperouge, self-appointed leader of a terrorist movement opposing the Britannia Empire's occupation of Japan

"His friends are his sidekicks and his worst nightmare"

> Lelouch's best friend, Suzaku Kururugi, works for the Britannian military, opposing the terrorists in his advanced Knightmare Frame mecha. Another of his schoolfriends, Kallen Stadtfeld, is a prominent member of the resistance.

"His hobbies are ripping off royals"

> The members of the Britannian royalty are the main villains of the series.

"and controlling people"

> Lelouch has the power of Geass, which allows him to give someone a single vocal command that they are compelled to obey.

"But in the end he's a real good guy"

> He's the protagonist... though tbh I wouldn't say he's a "good guy". He does some pretty terrible things in the name of opposing the Britannian regime.

Hint (note, this actually does spoil the anime):

> Season 1 ends with Lelouch and Suzaku holding each other at gunpoint. We hear a gunshot... cue end credits. I never actually watched Season 2, but from what I've heard it has a completely different storyline to Season 1.

Comment: Regarding feedback, I would say this one is a bit too obvious. The clues need to be more abstract.

Comment: Have you tried the [newest riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75379/anime-guess-riddle-4)?

Comment: I've had a look, and it does look a little more abstract. I'm not sure I know the answer but I'll thinking about it.