# Anime guess Riddle #3

Tags: wordplay, knowledge

[Like in my second part](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75280/anime-guess-riddle-2), I'm searching for the name of an anime. Knowledge from the anime is required so maybe, if you haven't seen it, you can't figure it out. I hope you have fun :)

> So Mr. ... you're really that small? OK, it just distracted me. Let's begin with our job interview. You are 21 years old. What are your hobbies?
> Well I do all kinds of stuff, during my time staying abroad I came across thieves and world destructing plans. I eventually caught some of them myself, but I never charged money for it. In retrospect I should have, it could have been useful for a bike. Well that's what I do most of the time.
> Ehh, OK. This is an employment offer for a professor. You won't be the next Indiana Jones here.

Bonus: Should the person take the offer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wild Guess Alert!

> Pokėmon (gotta catch 'em all!)

*So Mr. ... you're really that small? OK, it just distracted me. Let's begin with our job interview. You are 21 years old. What are your hobbies?*

> Pokėmon is 21 years old, but Ash Ketchum is always 10.

*Well I do all kinds of stuff, during my time staying abroad I came across thieves and world destructing plans. I eventually caught some of them myself, but I never charged money for it. In retrospect I should have, it could have been useful for a bike. Well that's what I do most of the time.*

> Ash stays in several different regions, where he encounters Team Rocket (thieves) and world destructing plans (he's come across several). He never charges money, and the bike in the original Pokėmon games is the most expensive item in that game.

*Ehh, OK. This is an employment offer for a professor. You won't be the next Indiana Jones here.*

> Each Pokėmon region has a professor.

Should he take the offer?

> **Yes** because all of the Pokėmon professors are named after trees, and 'ash' is a tree!

Comment: You're right. Didn't think that was so easy. Did you consider rot13(Qrgrpgvir Pbana) or what made you think of this?

Comment: @Jannis it's the only anime I know, lol. also (rot13) ybbx ng zl hfreanzr :)