# Anime guess Riddle #4

Tags: wordplay, knowledge

[Like in my third part](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75289/anime-guess-riddle-3), I'm searching for the name of an anime. Knowledge from the anime is required so maybe, if you havent seen it, you cant figure it out. I hope you have fun :)

> Braveheart story retold:
>   Once upon a time in a galaxy far far away
>   Was a painted firefighter, who invented the cryostasis,
>   who settled things with ghosts and a fiery stalker and his dad.
>   He died and respawned as a woman doing the same all over again

PS: I had some issues with the quality of these riddles. Was this riddle good? Should I make more? Should I change sth? How could I've made it better?

Comment: This is still not a puzzle. It's "identify this anime". Trivia questions are *not* puzzles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it

> Avatar: The Last Airbender?

Braveheart story retold:

> Fighting against the tyrants. Also, the main character has the blue arrow on the head, kinda reminds me on the blue paint of the main character from Braveheart. :)

Once upon a time in a galaxy far far away
Was a painted firefighter, who invented the cryostasis,

> This refers to Aang who is fighting against the firebenders

who settled things with ghosts and a fiery stalker and his dad.

> The ghosts refer to the previous avatars, fiery stalker is Zuko, and his dad is named Ozai

He died and respawned as a woman doing the same all over again

> There is a sequal of this anime, and the main character is a girl named Korra.

Comment: what about cryostasis, and the painting of braveheart

Comment: Also... Avatar isn't anime...?

Comment: @generalcrispy what do you mean it isn't anime?

Comment: It doesn't originate from Japan. It has a few anime stylizations in it, but it's purely an American cartoon. (IMO, it's the best one, though.)