# Anime guess Riddle #5

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

Like in my [fourth part](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75379/anime-guess-riddle-4?noredirect=1&lq=1), I'm searching for the name of an anime. There is no knowledge about this anime needed to solve it, but it helps! I hope you have fun :)

> When the plants are cutted,
>   by the deft blades
>   the lawnmowing otakus
>   are on fire
>   just for it.
>   Due to treacherous plastic, this game
>   hurts a bit, but it
>   still spread epidemicly

@Deusovi it's definetly a riddle this time :)

> Does my bad formatting mean something?

Comment: Is cutted instead of cut and lawnmoving instead of mowing intentional?

Comment: @gabbo1092 I'm sry it's meant mowing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be

> Beyblade?

When the plants are cutted,
by the deft blades
the lawnmowing otakus
are on fire
just for it.

> This maybe describes the start of the beyblade match

Due to treacherous plastic, this game
hurts a bit, but it
still spread epidemicly

> This may refer to the fact that there are popular beyblade toys made of plastic.

Comment: rot13(svefg 5 yvarf ersre gb gur puvyqvfu gel ynjazbjvat jvgu orloynqrf naq gur 6 yvar fnlf gur chyyvat ebcrf uheg vs gurl uvg lbh (jung unccrarq fbzrgvzrf). Nyfb gur 2 yrggre bs gur guveq jbeq va rnpu yvar fnl 'yrg vg evc')

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> Sword Art Online (SAO)?

Because:

> The first few lines seem to be about swords.
>  Fire looks pretty and so does art.
>  It's about playing a game online or something using plastic computer peripherals that can give you RSI, and news/memes spread online fast like an epidemic.

Comment: sry but your answer is incorrect