# Anime guess Riddle #7

Tags: rebus, knowledge

Like in my [sixth part](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75763/anime-guess-riddle-6), I'm searching for the name of an anime. There is no knowledge about this anime needed to solve it, but it helps! I hope you have fun :)
This time I made a picture riddle:
[image: riddle]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer:

> Yu-Gi-Oh!

Reason:

> First pic is pointing at **YOU**. (**EDIT** *Pic was changed to a **U** shaped horseshoe.*)
>  Second pic is a **GI** used in martial arts.
>  Third pic is Pikachu making an **OH** surprised face.

Comment: thats completely correct... in the moment I posted i had a better idea for the first picture +1 from me