# Anime guess Riddle #8

Tags: wordplay, knowledge

Like in my [seventh part](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75785/anime-guess-riddle-7), I'm searching for the name of an anime. There is  knowledge about this anime needed to solve it! I hope you have fun :)
This time I've updated the Pokemon theme so it fits another anime:

> I am the very best
>   Like no one ever was
>   To kill them is no real test
>   To find someone is my cause
>   I will travel across the land
>   Searching far and wide
>   Teach my disciple to understand
>   The power that's inside
>
> (Pokémon, gotta kill'em all) It's mostly just me
>   I dont care about my destiny
>   (Pokémon) Oh, I have some friends
>   In a world we must defend
>   (Pokémon, gotta kill'em all) A heart so true
>   My laziness will pull us through
>   You teach me and I'll teach you
>   Pokémon! (Gotta kill'em all) Gotta kill'em all
>
> Every challenge along the way
>   With hope I will face
>   I will battle every day
>   To claim my rightful peace
>   Come with me, the time is right
>   There's no better team
>   Arm in arm we'll win the fight
>   It's always been our dream
>
> chorus repeats here

Comment: One of your best so far, cant wait for #10

Comment: @Doomenik [there you go](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78311/anime-guess-riddle-9)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this doesn't work as well with the last bit, but maybe it's

> One-Punch Man

Potential Spoilers ahead.

I am the very best
Like no one ever was

> No one else (that we know of yet) can match him (Saitama). I don't recall for sure, but I don't think there's been an enemy yet that lasts more than a single punch soo...

To kill them is no real test

> He kills monsters/aliens in one punch.

To find someone is my cause
I will travel across the land
Searching far and wide

> A couple of the episodes are of him going places in search of a worthy opponent.

Teach my disciple to understand
The power that's inside

> The cyborg hero kid (Genos), but he follows Saitama trying to learn and develop a similar strength.

It's mostly just me
I dont care about my destiny

> Saitama is just doing things mostly because he's bored.

Oh, I have some friends
In a world we must defend

> He groups together with some other characters to defend from, iirc, an alien ship or something.

A heart so true
My laziness will pull us through

> He's bored mostly, but also isn't super motivated (?). Also, he's pretty blunt/forward and honest about how he feels and what his understanding is.

You teach me and I'll teach you

> Saitama also learns some things from Genos, such as learning about the hero association. (@Jannis)

Every challenge along the way
With hope I will face

> Saitama is hoping to find something challenging again.

I will battle every day
To claim my rightful peace

> In the episode with the house of evolution his peace is disturbed by the attack. (@Jannis)

Come with me, the time is right
There's no better team
Arm in arm we'll win the fight
It's always been our dream

> Perhaps this refers to that final fight of season 1 with the monster ship?

Yeah, apparently my memory is a bit fuzzier on the subject than I thought. Just waiting for the next season before I rewatch.

Some of these are still a little rough. Thanks to @Jannis though for helping me fill in the gaps.

Comment: Maybe add your elaboration anyways. Even if it is wrong it may help lead others to an answer.

Comment: Its right :) in most of your unknown sentences i also didnt what to add/change. so rot13 (V jvyy onggyr rirel qnl/
Gb pynvz zl evtugshy crnpr:
Va gur rcvfbqr jvgu gur ubhfr bs ribyhgvba uvf crnpr vf qvfgheorq ol gur nggnpx. 
-Lbh grnpu zr naq V'yy grnpu lbh:
Nyfb ur yrneaf cerggl zhpu sebz uvf qvfpvcyr, fb ur urnef nobhg gur ureb betnavmngvba sebz trabf)

Comment: Sweet. Nifty idea. Thanks for the clarifications/reminders! I'll update my answer with those details so it's more cohesive.