# Anime guess Riddle #9

Tags: wordplay, knowledge

Had not too much time to spend the last month, so here is the 9th part of the series
Like in [my eighth part](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/76013/anime-guess-riddle-8), I'm searching for the name of an anime. There is knowledge about this anime needed to solve it! I hope you have fun :)

> **How to make a weird story**
>   Have a protagonist who is powerless. Give the protagonist superpowers and a new outfit. Make the protagonist aware of the poor outfit coverage. Make the protagonist proud of it. Give the protagonist a best friend. Let the best friend have her own theme and the most hyperactive family at all. Let the antagonist almost kill everyone using only clothes. Let the antagonist be actually a good person who saves all unnessesary endagered persons and uncover the real evilous person. Get the protagonist unconscious with a scissor. Wake the protagonist up in an distopian world. Make the protagonist evil. Unevil the protagonist instantly. Kill a giant cocoon with a ship. Let the protagonist absorb the powers of randoms to shout at a satellite. Kill the best friend. END
>
> I forgot to mention to say that they fight. Every Episode.

Comment: This is the first I´m not getting quite fast, so I hope it is something I never saw.. Is it something out of the rot13(Zntvpny tvey) series?

Comment: @Brandon_J was a typo, was earlier bring the world to the egde of despair, but that didnt fit right. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's:

> [Kill la Kill](https://myanimelist.net/anime/18679/Kill_la_Kill)
>  since it was about *uniform* and *powerless* at the start

Careful of the spoiler:

- Have a protagonist who is powerless.

  > Matoi the protagonist transfers to a new school which is Honnouji Academy. High school dominated by its fearsome student council, who wear powerful Goku Uniforms that grant them superhuman abilities. She is easily beaten in the early episode by the boxing club captain, who uses the power of his Goku Uniform.
- Give the protagonist superpowers and a new outfit.

  > Fleeing to her ruined home nearby, Ryuko is dropped down a trapdoor by her homeroom teacher, Aikuro Mikisugi. She lands in a basement and discovers a living sailor uniform that forcibly puts itself on her.
- Make the protagonist aware of the poor outfit coverage. Make the protagonist proud of it.

  > Bad outfit design, yet give her power to fight.
- Give the protagonist a best friend. Let the best friend have her own theme and the most hyperactive family at all.

  > [Mako Mankanshoku](https://myanimelist.net/character/91675/Mako_Mankanshoku)
- Let the antagonist bring the world almost kill everyone using only clothes.

  > [Satsuki Kiryuuin](https://myanimelist.net/character/83799/Satsuki_Kiryuuin)
- Let the antagonist be actually a good person who saves all unnessesary endagered persons and uncover the real evilous person.

  > Satsuki [mother](https://myanimelist.net/character/96877/Ragyou_Kiryuuin) is the real evil.
- Get the protagonist unconscious with a scissor. Wake the protagonist up in an distopian world. Make the protagonist evil. Unevil the protagonist instantly. Kill a giant cocoon with a ship. Let the protagonist absorb the powers of randoms to shout at a satellite. Kill the best friend. END

  > Not sure about this one, kind of forget the ending.
- I forgot to mention to say that they fight. Every Episode.

  > Yeah, literally every single one.

Comment: Hey same answer - glad to know I'm right haha

Comment: Great explanation and nice anime over there :)

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this out there:

Is this

> Kill la Kill? The scissor comment led me there and the Wikipedia entry (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_la_Kill) matched your story-line fairly well.

Must admit - found this via careful Google searches, not Anime knowledge.

Comment: I should've accepted your answer since you were first, but Mukyuu had more detail

Comment: No problem! I kind of cheated, anyway, since I Googled it without knowledge of the series. :)

Comment: You are a f****ing master. When I google for sth I dont know, I never find it. And the cheating isn't actually cheating. I didn't forbid it. There is even a tag for not googling

Comment: haha had no idea about the tag. And yeah I can rock google sometimes lol.